# How to Unit test the following method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, nunit, moq

```
public User AddTags(int userId, List<Tag> Tags)
            {
                var user = GetUserById(userId);
                Tags.ForEach( tag => user.Tags.Add(tag));
                return _repository.Update(user);
            }
public interface IRepository<T> where T:class 
    {
        void Add(T item);
        void Remove(T item);
        T Update(T item);
    }
```

In the test class

```
protected IRepository<User> Repository;
protected UserService Service;
public Mock<IRepository<User>> MockUserRepository = new Mock<IRepository<User>>();
Repository = MockUserRepository.Object;
Service = new UserService(UnitOfWork, Repository);
//I don't quite understand how to mock the Update method.
var result = Service.AddUserTags(1,Tags);
Assert.AreEqual(result.UserTags.Count(),3);
```

I have a `List<User> users` and a `List<Tag> tags`.

I am using EF , NUnit ,MOQ and the generic repository pattern.

Edit :

In GetUserById

```
return _repository.GetAll().Where(_ => _.UserId == userId).SingleOrDefault();

I have mocked it doing the following 

MockUserRepository.Setup(_ => _.GetAll()).Returns(Users.AsQueryable());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I depends on what happens in `GetUserById(userId);`.  In order to check the count of `UserTags` you must control the returned `User` by mocking the `GetUserId`.

Otherwise, the best you can do is to make sure that the `Update` method is called:

```
repository.Verify(x => x.Update(It.IsAny<User>()));
```

After edit:
Then, you would need to setup the User:

```
[TestFixture]
    public class TestPointer
    {
        private IRepository<User> Repository;
        private UserService Service;
        private Mock<IRepository<User>> MockUserRepository = new Mock<IRepository<User>>();

        [Test]
        public void GetItemsByUserName_UserName_ListOfItems()
        {
            //Arrange
            var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
            Service = new UserService(unitOfWork,  MockUserRepository.Object);
            var Tags = new List<Tag>() { new Tag { Name = "TestTag1" }, new Tag { Name = "TestTag2" }, new Tag { Name = "TestTag3" } };
            var user = new User() {Id = 1};
            MockUserRepository.Setup(x => x.Find(1)).Returns(user);
            MockUserRepository.Setup(x => x.Update(user)).Returns(user);

            //Act
            var result = Service.AddTags(1, Tags);


            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(result.Tags.Count(),3);
        }
    }

    public class UserService
    {
        private IRepository<User> _repository;
        private UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public UserService(UnitOfWork unitOfWork, IRepository<User> repository)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public User AddTags(int userId, List<Tag> Tags)
        {
            var user = GetUserById(userId);
            Tags.ForEach(tag => user.Tags.Add(tag));
            return _repository.Update(user);
        }

        private User GetUserById(int userId)
        {
            return _repository.Find(userId);
        }
    }

    public class UnitOfWork
    {

    }

    public interface IRepository<T> where T:class
    {
        T Find(int id);
        void Add(T item);
        void Remove(T item);
        T Update(T item);
    }

    public class User
    {
        private List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag>();

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<Tag> Tags
        {
            get { return tags; }
            set { tags = value; }
        }
    }

    public class Tag
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the count be 4 after you add the tag, no real update seems to be happening ?

Comment: How do you get 4?  I'm adding 3 tags, yes?  And, no real update is happening because we are mocking the repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assert on what happens with the user, The `GetuserById` method should should be injected, so it can be replaced by a mock, that returns a mocked user. You can then verify, that the `user.Tags.Add(tag)` is called the right number of times.

After that, you can verify that `_repository.Update(user)` is called one time;

For veryfication syntax in Moq, check [this](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) link.

Comment: Should I be even checking for the  right number of calls ? If I foreach over the list then except for checking for nulls what is the purpose of such an Assert ?

Comment: It verifies that the logic in your loop is correct, so I would say so, eventhoug the logic is straightforward.